# Compile Error in VirtualButtonBehaviour syntax

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

I am creating a small app using Unity/Vuforia engines and when i loop through for virtual buttons i am getting the below compilation error.

```
using System.Collections;    
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using UnityEngine;    
using Vuforia;

public class XYZScript : MonoBehaviour,IVirtualButtonEventHandler { 
    public GameObject xgo, ygo;
// Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        VirtualButtonBehaviour[] vrb = GetComponentInChildren<VirtualButtonBehaviour>();
        for(int i=0; i<vrb.Length; i++)
        {
            vrb[i].RegisterEventHandler(this);
        }
        xgo.SetActive(false);
        ygo.SetActive(false);        
    }
```

I am getting the error at

```
VirtualButtonBehaviour[] vrb = GetComponentInChildren<VirtualButtonBehaviour>();
```

Error Message:

> This behavior associates a Virtual Button with a game object. Use the functionality in ImageTargetBehavior to create and destroy Virtual Buttons at run-time.
>
> Cannot implicity covert type "Vuforia.VirtualButtonBehaviour" to
> "Vuforia.VirtualButtonBehaviour[]"

Comment: The second one is a typo and you probably wanted to use `GetComponentsInChildren` (note the `s`). (Hint: you might also want to pass it the `true` as parameter in orser to also get components on disabled children.)  The first error message is quite self-explanatory I think..

Comment: [GetComponent**s**InChildren](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html) != [GetComponentInChildren](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html)

Comment: @derHugo Thanks a ton ! It works great !!

Answer (score 0):

VirtualButtonBehaviour[] vrb = GetComponentInChildren();

You must change GetComponentInChildren
Use **GetComponentsInChildren**

Comment: You copied this answer from the comments. It's only been a typo.